# object Object has no method

Tags: jquery, nomethoderror

Right having a crazy issue here.

Cant really paste the code so this is more a theory question

I've got jquery included first, then all my jquery plugins

all the plugins are loaded as a dropped a console.log inside each to show it was linked.

however on EVERY plugin when it tries to use it it returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'PLUGIN FUNCTION'
```

theoretically what could be happening

Comment: you are calling an undefined function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct answer seems to be...

I somehow was calling jQuery twice, so the 2nd initation of jQuery was unloading all the previous loaded plugins.